# parseJSON into SQL Server from URL

Tags: sql-server, json, t-sql

I am wondering how I could parse JSON data into sql server from url?

I tried this method [click here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/consuming-json-strings-in-sql-server/) to parseJSON into SQL server by copying and pasting the JSON data.

I read about [this](http://blog.dotnetframework.org/2010/09/01/make-a-http-request-from-sql-server/) method using HTTP request from SQL server, but 8000 bytes isn't a lot.

Is there any other way?

Comment: You can search some for `.net` implementation and create `SQL CLR` objects or upgrade to `SQL Server 2016`, because  `JSON` native support  is implemented with it.

Comment: parseJSON is custom tsql function. It may or may not work. What is your scrpting language?